# List Index Out Of Range in Python (IF statement)

Tags: python, arrays, range

I was messing around, here is the "erroring" part of my code, I think it isn't necessary for you to know more:

```
def parse(toks):
    i = 0
    while(i < len(toks)):
        if toks[i] + " " + toks[i+1][0:6] == "CMD_SHOW STRING" or toks[i] + " " + toks[i+1][0:3] == "CMD_SHOW NUM" or toks[i] + " " + toks[i+1][0:4] == "CMD_SHOW EXPR":
            if toks[i+1][0:6] == "STRING":
                doPRINT(toks[i+1])

            elif toks[i+1][0:3] == "NUM":
                doPRINT(toks[i+1])

            elif toks[i+1][0:4] == "EXPR":
                doPRINT(toks[i+1])

            i += 2

        if toks[i][0:3] + " " + toks[i+1] + " " + toks[i+2][0:6] == "VAR EQUALS STRING" or toks[i][0:3] + " " + toks[i+1] + " " + toks[i+2][0:3] == "VAR EQUALS NUM" or toks[i][0:3] + " " + toks[i+1] + " " + toks[i+2][0:4] == "VAR EQUALS EXPR":
            if toks[i+2][0:6] == "STRING":
                doASSIGN(toks[i], toks[i+2])

            elif toks[i+2][0:3] == "NUM":
                doASSIGN(toks[i], toks[i+2])

            elif toks[i+2][0:4] == "EXPR":
                doASSIGN(evalExpression(toks[i], toks[i+2]))

            i += 3
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kuba\Desktop\Programowanie\Projekty\Amai\amailexparse.py", line
 135, in parse
    if toks[i][0:3] + " " + toks[i+1] + " " + toks[i+2][0:6] == "VAR EQUALS STRI
NG" or toks[i][0:3] + " " + toks[i+1] + " " + toks[i+2][0:3] == "VAR EQUALS NUM"
 or toks[i][0:3] + " " + toks[i+1] + " " + toks[i+2][0:4] == "VAR EQUALS EXPR":
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I've tried many things, changing value of i, array size changing, and statement decreasing. Can anyone help me with this? It's for my online school project, so I would need help fast.

Comment: Try printing out values of `i` in the loop, as well as perhaps `i+1` and `i+2` since you access the array with those indices. Compare what you see with `len(toks)`. You'll quickly find the error.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue you  can change the while loop condition of the loop to the following:

```
while( (i+2) < len(toks) )
```